# Integer to boolean conversion in count() method

Tags: python

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3].count(True)

>>> 3
```

Why does this return `3` instead of `6`, if `bool(i)` returns `True` for all values `i` not equal to `0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [33]: True == 1
Out[33]: True

In [34]: True == 2
Out[34]: False

In [35]: True == 3
Out[35]: False
```

`True` and `False` are instances of `bool`, and `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/numbers.html#numbers.Integral):

> [Booleans] represent the truth values False and True. The two objects
>   representing the values False and True are the only Boolean objects.
>   The Boolean type is a subtype of plain integers, and **Boolean values
>   behave like the values 0 and 1, respectively, in almost all contexts**,
>   the exception being that when converted to a string, the strings
>   "False" or "True" are returned, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

This is better done with a comprehension:

```
>>> sum(1 for i in [1,1,1,2,2,3,0] if i)
6
```

or

```
sum(bool(i) for i in [1,1,1,2,2,3,0])
```

Or count the opposite way, since there is no ambiguity about False is something other than 0

```
>>> li=[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0]
>>> len(li) - li.count(False)
6
```

Better still:

```
sum(map(bool,li))
```

Comment: I should have clarified that it wasn't code I was actually intending to use--I was just experimenting with the interpreter, finding edge cases and such.

Comment: No, no, I appreciate the input. The more I can learn, the better.

Comment: Don't do comparisons of '== True' or '!= True', just treat the values as booleans: `sum(1 for i in seq if i)`, or simpler, `sum(bool(i) for i in seq)`, or simplest `sum(map(bool,seq))`.

Comment: Here's a surprise: `sum(not not i for i in seq)` is twice as fast as `sum(bool(i) for i in seq)` (using timeit module).

Comment: Function calls are very expensive in Python... While you are timing, what about `map(bool,li)`?